# how to use async and await in timer

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, httpwebrequest, async-await

My windows app's requirement are:

1. Using HttpWebRequest get web request/response every 3 seconds in one thread.(total is about 10 threads for doing this web request/response.)
2. Each thread use some global variables.

I want to use a System.Timers.Timer and async and await. But I don't know that is a best way for high performance. And then how to test them. I am a green in C#.

Comment: Do you *have* to use Timer? Are you allowed to use `Task.Delay()` instead? I can show you an example if so.

Comment: @user2724902, you don't need to create 10 threads for doing `HttpWebRequest` in parallel. Use `WebRequest.GetResponseAsync`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could write a `RepeatActionEvery()` method as follows.

It's parameters are:

- `action` - The action you want to repeat every so often.
- `interval` - The delay interval between calling `action()`.
- `cancellationToken` - A token you use to cancel the loop.

Here's a compilable console application that demonstrates how you can call it. For an ASP application you would call it from an appropriate place.

Note that you need a way to cancel the loop, which is why I pass a `CancellationToken` to `RepeatActionEvery()`. In this sample, I use a cancellation source which automatically cancels after 8 seconds. You would probably have to provide a cancellation source for which some other code called `.Cancel()` at the appropriate time. [See here for more details.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364)

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    sealed class Program
    {
        void run()
        {
            CancellationTokenSource cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource(
              TimeSpan.FromSeconds(8));
            Console.WriteLine("Starting action loop.");
            RepeatActionEvery(() => Console.WriteLine("Action"), 
              TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), cancellation.Token).Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Finished action loop.");
        }

        public static async Task RepeatActionEvery(Action action, 
          TimeSpan interval, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                action();
                Task task = Task.Delay(interval, cancellationToken);

                try
                {
                    await task;
                }
                catch (TaskCanceledException)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason to favor catching the TaskCanceledException rather than checking the cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested property in place of true statement in the while condition?

Comment: @EhouarnPerret If you pass the cancellationToken to `Task.Delay()` then it will throw `TaskCanceledException` if the token is cancelled, so you MUST catch the exception.

Comment: my bad I was expecting another behaviour about the cancellation in the Task.Delay without having checked the msdn, sigh.
Anyway, thanks it perfectly makes sense to me now.

Comment: I tried to implement this in a flutter program (flutter uses Dart as a base) and these functions don't seem to appear.  Is there any particular reason that you can think of why that is, or better yet, any plausible solutions?