# Run function every few seconds in background without blocking UI c#

Tags: c#, async-await, task

How can I run a task every few seconds using task async await without blocking UI. Below is my sample using timer. I was able to run function every few seconds but it is blocking the UI. Can someone please help me out i'm new to asynchronous programming.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gridControl1.DataSource = GetData();
            timer.Interval = 5000;
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(MyTimer_Tick);
            timer.Start();
        }


        private void MyTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           gridControl1.DataSource = GetData();
           gridControl1.RefreshDataSource();
        }

        DataTable GetData()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Value1", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value2", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value3", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value4", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value5", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value6", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value7", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value8", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value9", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value10", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value11", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value12", typeof(int));

            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int i = 1; i < 1000000; i++)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(rnd.Next(1, 100), rnd.Next(1, 100), rnd.Next(1, 100),
                    rnd.Next(1, 100), rnd.Next(1, 100), rnd.Next(1, 100), rnd.Next(1, 100), rnd.Next(1, 100), rnd.Next(1, 100),
                    rnd.Next(1, 100), rnd.Next(1, 100), rnd.Next(1, 100));
            }
            return dt;
        }
```

Comment: what version of C# are you using?

Comment: @RJProgrammer - i'm using version 4.6

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using a `System.Forms.Timer`, which raises its event on the UI thread. So, you'll want to push any long-blocking work to a background thread:

```
private async void MyTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 gridControl1.DataSource = await Task.Run(() => GetData());
 gridControl1.RefreshDataSource();
}
```

Comment: @user what's the difference between what I suggested a what Stephen has suggested, for you to say it works better.

I have suggested exactly same thing, just that its refactored to create `GetDataAsync`

Comment: @MrinalKamboj: Your solution uses `Task.Run` in the implementation of a (fake) asynchronous method. My solution uses `Task.Run` to *call* a synchronous method. More info [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html).

Comment: @StephenCleary, Thanks for the clarification, would be careful in the future

Answer (score -1):

You will need first to define GetData as an async method do so by changing the return type:

```
Task<DataTable> GetData(){...}
```

also to match the Guideline you may want to add async to the method name

```
Task<DataTable> GetDataAsync(){...}
```

<s>then you may want to cover all code in GetDataAsync method by Task.Factory.StartNew</s>

```
Task<DataTable> GetData(){
  return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
     ...
      return dt;
   });
}
```

**EDIT:** 
As suggested by @MrinalKamboj
use Task.Run Insted

```
Task<DataTable> GetData(){
string result = await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            ...
           return dt;

        });

    return result;
}
```

for repeating the task you may want to get rid of timer and look at this answer:
[RepeatActionEvery Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22449518/how-to-use-async-and-await-in-timer)

hope that helps.

Comment: Solution pointed is for Console, will not work for Winforms, will lead to deadlock on calling`Wait`

Comment: @MrinalKamboj true but the link provided is intended for the method itself. to use it he will need to async form_load and use await keyword.

Comment: Please check the solutions underneath, we don't need `Form_Load` as `Async`